# Can't see data on the rails console but exists on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I load my website on development mode on `localhost:3000` and I can see that there are data like users, portfolios, etc.
But when I open the rails console, I can't see the data. I get empty arrays:

```
 r00t$ rails console development
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
1.9.3-p484 :001 > User.all
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
1.9.3-p484 :002 > Portfolio.all
  Portfolio Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
1.9.3-p484 :003 >
```

I opened console with `RAILS_ENV=development rails console` too and I still get empty arrays...

Any clue? Thanks

Comment: what if you add an object from the console? is it visible in your browser? and in the console? You could also check in your db directly if object really exist. Are you sure you're consulting the same db from console and from the server?

Comment: @sissy excellent. thank you, i used export DATABASE_URL before and forgot about it.

Comment: @sissy would be nice if you write this comment an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: ok i'll do it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem could be that you're consulting different databases from the console and from the browser. Try to check if you add an object from the console if it is present also in the database you'e using or if by mistake you created a different database.